# Is ObjectDB JPQL different from normal JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, objectdb

I was discussing with someone about comparisons in JPQL, I gave him this link, http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/comparison, I think that ObjectDB uses the normal JPQL and so it sufficed the question. But someone told me that it is ObjectDB's JPQL so it is not useful, to a degree. Is this true because it doesn't seem that way in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is exactly the same JPQL.

In this specific documentation page, the right column in the first table is about Java and JDO operators  (as explained explicitly in the page), but everything else is about pure JPA and JPQL.

Every JPA implementation, and ObjectDB as well, includes various extensions to the standard. But extensions of ObjectDB are explicitly specified as extensions in the documentation.